# How to substitute text with an icon inside a button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, icons

I included the following dropdown Bootstrap button on my webpage:

```
<!-- Example single danger button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to substitute the text `Action` with the following icon:

```
<i class="fas fa-language"></i>
```

I've been trying with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button id="translate"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How might it substitute the text of a button with an icon?

- S O L V E D - - - - - ->

I added the following in the  of the HTML file, as recommended, and it solved the problem:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you did the right thing already. Can you please try to put that FontAwesome Icon somewhere else and check that FontAwesome is properly loaded?

Comment: @arnonuem  I tried, it doesn't work...

Comment: I know I just wanted to point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
                <button id="translate"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: where did you take the libraries you put in the <head>?